# Как обновить часть информации из базы данных на странице не перезагружая ее

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Весь код выполняется в одном файле index.php. Все выводится вот, но чтобы появились новые строки приходится перезагружать страницу :(. Вот собственно код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Тестовое задание</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  id="send_form" method="post">
            Имя<input type="text" name="name" value="Василий" />
            email<input type="text" name="email" value="n.vasilencov@yandex.ru" />
            Комментарий<input type="text" name="comment" value="Всем доволен" />
            <input type="button" id="send" value="Записать">
        </form>
        <script>

        </script>
<!- ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ Я ОТПРАВЛЯЮ В БД ФОРМУ ->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("#send").click(function(){
                        var data = $("#send_form").serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'back/form_send.php',
                            type: "POST",
                            data:data ,
                            success: function(data) {
                             console.log(data);
                        }});
                    return false; 
                    });
            </script>
<!- ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ Я ОТПРАВЛЯЮ В БД ФОРМУ ->
    </body>
    </html>
<!-А ЗДЕСЬ ВЫВОДЯТСЯ ВСЕ ЗАПИСИ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ->
    <?php
    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '0000';
    $db_name = 'base';
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);    

    $mysqli = $link;
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT `name`, `email`, `comment` FROM `comments`");
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "{$result['name']}: {$result['email']}: {$result['comment']}<br>";
    }
    $mysqli->close();
        ?>
<!-А ЗДЕСЬ ВЫВОДЯТСЯ ВСЕ ЗАПИСИ ИЗ ТАБЛИЦЫ->
```

Подскажите, может я неправильно вывод из таблицы реализовываю??

Comment: И что - строки выводятся после body?

Comment: Не очень понятна логика - все выполняется в одном файле? Вы выводите данные на странице и делаете запрос на обновление в этой же странице?

Comment: Чтобы страница обновлялась автоматически или блок страницы обновлялся автоматически, нужно сделать ajax запрос в таймере. Всё. А писать записи таблицы после `</body></html>` должны только альтернативно одарённые люди

Comment: @ArchDemon Как сделать ajax запрос в базу?

Comment: Не в базу, а к скрипту php. Как? Да у в вашем коде пример есть.